# Could not find file 'bin\System.Web.Extensions.dll'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5/.NET 4.5.1 ASP.NET application that I am trying to publish to a local folder before zipping up said folder's contents and copying it to the server.  When attempting this, I get this error:

`Could not find file 'bin\System.Web.Extensions.dll'`

The bigger error is:

`Copying file bin\System.Web.Extensions.dll to obj\Qa\Package\PackageTmp\bin\System.Web.Extensions.dll failed. Could not find file 'bin\System.Web.Extensions.dll'`

I can build the app just fine and even run it without issue, but publishing gives me a problem.  I will note that I did recently delete the obj folder thinking it might resolve another unrelated issue I was having.  This was also originally a Webforms/.NET 4.0 project that I upgraded with VS 2013 so that it could also support MVC 5.

**Update**

While not really a solution, I located `System.Web.Extensions.dll` here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1`

I copied it to my bin folder and the publish now works.  However, I'd like to know what caused the issue in the first place.  I am still accepting answers and will delete the file from my bin to reproduce the issue so that I can test your solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in 'references' right click, `System.Web.Extensions` and go to 'properties' what is 'Copy Local' set to?

If you're copying to a machine which doesn't have the particular `.dll` installed, you need to make sure `Copy Local` is set to `True`.

EDIT:

I looked in my latest project and noticed copy local is 'False' but the reference is part of .Net 4.5

I'd suspect you're copying to a machine without .NET 4.5 installed?